# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Code Review's [second moderator election](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Vogel612] [image: rolfl] [image: Malachi]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking the moderators who are stepping down from the role:

- [Mathieu Guindon](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/putting-down-my-mug)
- [janos](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8669/passing-on-the-mod-hat)
- [200_success](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/nothing-fishy-going-on-here-nope-not-at-all)

Did I miss anyone? ;-)

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6327478414999552/0).

Comment: snaps snaps snaps

Answer (score 19):

Congratulations @Vogel612 and @Malachi, enjoy your new toys - it's awesome to see "new blood" (sort of!) in the moderator team!

@rolfl, welcome back home, and congratulations to you as well - I never had the slightest doubt you'd be [re-?]elected!

The site is in good hands. Now get to work! :p

Comment: You're throwing me off, new avatar, new name and no diamond. WHO IS THIS GUY?!

Comment: @Raystafarian I'd argue that this name predates the mug by a good 30 years ;-)

Comment: Never heard of him. Seems like someone I would have heard of by now.

Answer (score 13):

Bye, 200, janos, and Mat. I've learned a lot from you, and you've done a great job keeping the site clean. I don't think you could've done any better.

Welcome, Malachi and Vogel, and re-welcome, rolfl! I've learned a lot from you as well, and I'm sure you will do a great job as mod. I've seen you handling issues on and offsite (especially rolfl as a previous mod), and I doubt we could have found better replacements for our resignees if we searched the entire site.